# Prevent Gitlab from changing the shell

Tags: git, gitlab

So, I'm currently trying to make gitlab work on my server. This server is currently running git-list for several of my friends which are working on a few project with me. However, since gitlab offers more, we want to switch.

The problem which I have is that i still want git-list to work. However, when I try to do `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`, it switches the following line in my passwd file

```
git:x:1001:1001::/home/git:/usr/bin/git-shell
```

into

```
git:x:1001:1001::/var/opt/gitlab:/bin/sh
```

which prevents everyone from pushing. However, without changing this line, I can't pull or push anything from gitlab repositories.

So how can I make gitlab work without affecting our current git-list installation?

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt this behavior in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`. To keep GitLab from changing this line whilst reconfiguration you will need to adjust the `user['shell']` and `user['home_dir']` setting. (Do not forget to uncomment those lines!)

```
# # The shell for the git user
user['shell'] = "/usr/bin/git-shell"
# # The home directory for the git user
user['home'] = "/home/git"
```

However, I assume using both systems in parallel that way might not work - how could they both listen for SSH connections at the same time? So I would provide either GitLab or git-list with an own user.

(For more details, see [GitLab documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/configuration.md#changing-the-name-of-the-git-user-group).)